# Matching opposite of [[:blank:]] character class in sed

Tags: regex, sed, character-class

I cannot find a way to represent the inverse of a character class in sed.  If this were a perl-like environment I would use [^\s].  However in sed this appears to match non-s, not non-whitespace.

On a line of text (from gdrive) I need to capture the first non-whitespace token and ignore everything after (and including) the first whitespace on the line.

Here's a fake but representative example of the input I am trying to parse:

```
19845fake-FaKeE-xbk534sWsbBQ              mydir                                    dir               2019-01-01 19:10:44
```

My original attempt at doing this was the line:

```
sed -rn 's/^([^\s]*).*$/\1/p'
```

At first it seemed to work until I noticed that this is cutting off at the first 's', rather than the first whitespace.

I have since attempted various permutations like:

```
#matches up to the first 's'
 sed -rn 's/([^\\s]*).*$/\1/p'

#matches only the first character
 sed -rn 's/^([^[[:blank:]]]*).*$/\1/p'

#matches nothing at all
 sed -rn 's/^([[^:blank:]]*).*$/\1/p'



sed -rn 's/^\s*([^\s]*).*$/\1/p'
```

Expected: 19845fake-FaKeE-xbk534sWsbBQ

Actual:   19845fake-FaKeE-xbk534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character class is `[:blank:]` so to match the opposite of it, you just need `[^[:blank:]]`. This should work:

```
sed -rn 's/^([^[:blank:]]*).*$/\1/p'
```